# Vector multiplied by a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I am trying to find the divergence and the value at P;

$v = x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}[x, y, z], P: (3, -1, 4)$

What is going on in v? is that a vector multiplied by a function? What is that called?

Anyway I think v can we rewritten as $v = [x^{3}y^{2}z^{2}, x^{2}y^{3}z^{2}, x^{2}y^{2}z^{3}]$ and then I can just take the partial derivative from there. But what is going on in the original question?

Comment: How did you get from $x^2$ to $x^3$? Is one of those a typo?

Comment: sorry yes I completed the vector now, but it wasn't a typo. I'm asking if that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divergence is defined on vector fields and is a mapping of $\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ so that is a good indication that they are implying multiplication (although I would consider that to be an unnatural notation for it). In your case, the product would produce the vector field $v = \begin{bmatrix} x^3 y^2 z^2, & x^2 y^3 z^2, & x^2 y^2 z^3\end{bmatrix}.$ You obtain this by multiplying each component of the vector by the scalar. The divergence in cartesian coordinates would then be $$\text{div}(v)=\nabla \cdot v  = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v_3}{\partial z} = 9x^2 y^2 z^2.$$

Comment: But there isn't a scalar right? xyz is a function?

Comment: @Jwan622 scalars can be functions so yes $xyz$ is a non-constant scalar. A scalar is just something that has magnitude with no real sense of direction. $v$ is simply a vector valued function (or vector field) that is factored in terms of the scalar function $xyz$ and the vector valued function $[x,y,z]$.